# Compare times on same table and list uncommon time in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck at a query to compare different times on same table and list one of the common and all uncommon time.

```
        ID ID_STORE Opentime       Closetime
---------- -------- ---------- -------------------------------
         1        6 09:30:00       18:00:00
         2        6 09:30:00       18:00:00
         3        6 09:30:00       18:00:00
         4        6 09:30:00       18:00:00
         5        6 09:30:00       16:00:00
         6        6 10:30:00       15:00:00
```

Like In this table the output should be like

```
        ID ID_STORE Opentime       Closetime
---------- -------- ---------- -------------------------------
         4        6 09:30:00       18:00:00
         5        6 09:30:00       16:00:00
         6        6 10:30:00       15:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example you give, it looks to me like all you need is a `GROUP BY` and decide on what aggregate function you use on the `ID`.

I have used `MAX` as it returns the result as per your example.

```
SELECT MAX(ID), OpenTime, CloseTime
FROM   YourTable
GROUP BY
       OpenTime, CloseTime
```

You can read up on

- [Aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks, I missed group by clause

Answer (score 3):

AS I've observed, you are getting the latest `ID` on every unique opentime and closetime and on every store.

```
SELECT MAX(ID) as ID,
        ID_Store,
        OpenTime,
        CloseTime
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ID_Store,
        OpenTime,
        CloseTime
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause. And for `ID` you can use aggregate function like [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) or [`MIN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) as per your requirement.

```
SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID, ID_STORE, Opentime,  Closetime 
  FROM myTable 
  GROUP BY ID_STORE, Opentime, Closetime
```